# How to load string in unicode using Textract library in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I'm using [Textract](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract) and relatively new to Python and I would like to load a file in unicode string rather than utf-8. Is there a way to do that?

I tried

```
text = textract.process(file)
```

But this loads a UTF-8 string while I prefer unicode. I tried using

```
text = textract.process(file, encoding="unicode")
```

But this throws an error.

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moha/dev/intellij-ws/pyqadi/tests/test_file2txt.py", line 11, in test_process
    str=f2t.to_txt(file)
  File "/home/moha/dev/intellij-ws/pyqadi/textsearcher/file2txt.py", line 10, in to_txt
    text = textract.process(file, encoding="unicode")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textract/parsers/__init__.py", line 57, in process
    return parser.process(filename, encoding, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textract/parsers/utils.py", line 46, in process
    return self.encode(unicode_string, encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textract/parsers/utils.py", line 31, in encode
    return text.encode(encoding, 'ignore')
LookupError: unknown encoding: unicode
```

Comment: Utf-8 is a encoding for unicode strings. I do not understanding what you are asking. Could you explain? Could you add the output of `print type(text)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textract uses encoding to specify a particular output encoding (input encodings are inferred using [chardet](http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Here are the Uncidoe options for encoding:

```
unicode_escape, unicode_internal, raw_unicode_escape
text = textract.process(file, encoding = 'unicode_escape')
```

Here is an [exhaustive list](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line_interface.html).

The underlying data is in UTF-8.  You could take textract.processn as UTF-8 and decode it to Unicode on a separate line as such:

```
text = textract.process(file)

Utext = unicode(text,'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple method worked for me:

```
import textract as txt
text = txt.process(file)
text = text.decode("utf8")
```